# How to create a layout of 4 columns that one column has dynamic width and the other 3 are even?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not sure what's the best way to solve this.. I need layout of 4 columns, the first column has unknown (dynamic) width, the other 3 columns should fill the remaining space evenly. The tricky part is that **all columns must be direct siblings** of each other.

[image]

Preferably pure css solution

Comment: So if `element 1` has long text inside it should take 100% of window width?

Comment: you can assume element 1 has `white-space:nowrap;` applied so it will take as much space as it needs

Answer (score 4):

Flexbox can do that...

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.big {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  ;
}
.box {
  flex: 0 1 33%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="big">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="big">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with **JS**

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  var big = $('.big').outerWidth();
  var rest = ($(window).width() - big) / 3;
  $('.other').outerWidth(rest);
}).resize();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.big {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.column {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="column big">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</div>
  <div class="column other">Lorem</div>
  <div class="column other">Lorem</div>
  <div class="column other">Lorem</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using javascript, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hzkwxo3q/1/

HTML

```
<div id="col1" class="col1">
  <h1>
Dynamic
</h1>
</div>
<div id="col2" class="col2">
  <h1>
33%
</h1>
</div>
<div id="col3" class="col3">
  <h1>
33%
</h1>
</div>
<div id="col4" class="col4">
  <h1>
33%
</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.col1,
.col2,
.col3,
.col4 {
  min-width: 20%;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
}

.col1 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.col2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.col3 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.col4 {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

Javascript

```
  var width = document.getElementById('col1').clientWidth;
  var w = window.innerWidth;

  var extraSpace = (w - width) * 0.333;


  document.getElementById("col2").style.width = extraSpace + "px";
  document.getElementById("col3").style.width = extraSpace + "px";
  document.getElementById("col4").style.width = extraSpace + "px";
```